# SQL-Oracle Update table from itself using LAG()

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Lets assume we have a table like this one:

```
| Year | Month | Day | ID_Office | Operations | Operations yesterday |
|------|-------|-----|-----------|------------|----------------------|
| 2016 | 12    | 31  | 9555      | 500        | 0                    |
| 2017 | 1     | 1   | 9555      | 600        | 0                    |
| 2017 | 1     | 2   | 9555      | 750        | 0                    |
| 2017 | 1     | 3   | 9556      | 800        | 0                    |
```

I would like to update the value from "Operations yesterday" using "Operations" from the previous row. So the result table must be like this one:

```
| Year | Month | Day | ID_Office | Operations | Operations yesterday |
|------|-------|-----|-----------|------------|----------------------|
| 2016 | 12    | 31  | 9555      | 500        | 0                    |
| 2017 | 1     | 1   | 9555      | 600        | 500                  |
| 2017 | 1     | 2   | 9555      | 750        | 600                  |
| 2017 | 1     | 3   | 9556      | 800        | 0                    |
```

I'm using the following code with function LAG(), but it is not updating the correct value.

```
Update table1 F1
Set f1.operations_yesterday = 
                       (Select LAG(f1.operations, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY year, month, day)
                        From table1 F2
                        Where 
                        F1.year= F2.year And
                        F1.month= F2.month And
                        F1.day= F2.day);
```

Could you give me some advices from my code about what is exactly wrong?
I had success with lag() function on"Insert Into" statements, but in this case I must provide an Update statement solution.

NOTE:
Note that there could be more than three fields to be ordered by. I put as anexample only Year, Month and Day, but there are more fields not related to dates.
Also, it is important to detail that not everyday has values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't used `LAG()` myself, but I am wondering if you shouldn't have `f2` in the following piece of your script, instead of `f1`:  `...Select LAG(f1.operations, 1, 0)...`

Comment: @PeterAbolins Indeed, that is what is tried initially, but it still not working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not suggested to store data redundantly. However ...

You want to store data of the day before in your records. You suppose that there is a record for every day, so that *day before* would also be the *record before* ordered by date. But this knowledge doesn't really help, because it's way easier to select the day before than the record before.

It is very strange that you store day, month, and year separately instead of a mere date. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with this. We'll have to convert this clumsily.

```
update table1 today
set operations_yesterday =
(
  select operations
  from table1 yesterday
  where to_date(yesterday.year * 10000 + yesterday.month * 100 + yesterday.day, 'yyyymmdd')
      = to_date(today.year * 10000 + today.month * 100 + today.day, 'yyyymmdd') - 1
);
```

If you stored dates instead that would be simply:

```
update table1 today
set operations_yesterday =
      (select operations from table1 yesterday where yesterday.date = today.date - 1);
```

Add `COALESCE` (or Oracle's `NVL`), if you want 0 instead of null where there is no yesterday.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten Kettner.  However, there is something I missed to explain that may change the way you solved it. I put only three fields (Year, Month, Day) but there are more than these, and some of them are not related to Dates. Moreover, your second solution is not an option, because not every day has values.

Comment: @Roy90: How would the other columns come into play? Is there more than one column you want to update? What does "not every day has values" mean? That you separated the columns because a value can be null such as "in November 2016" without a day, or "every February 10" no matter what year?

Comment: As mentioned, you shouldn't do this anyway. It is very easy to select the record of the previous day. If you store these values in the current day's record, you store the data redundantly and this can lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: I have edited my initial post adding one more field. About "Not every day has values" I mean that It could be that some random days I do not insert values in the table and if you try to access to this concrete date there will be no data. Finally, I'm not exactly storing the value from the previuos day, I want this value to subtract from the current value and then store the result.

Comment: As to the additional column `ID_Office`: we don't do anything with it; it stays as it is. Exactly as it should be. As to missing days: Then we update with null. Exactly as it should be. As to storing a result: still you store the data redundantly. You can always just subtract one value from the other. If you store the values instead, you may at one day due to some mistake find previous day = 100, current day = 200, stored result = 50. What to do then? Which value is correct? Better don't store the result. As shown it is super-simple to select the previous day.

Comment: At the end, I used your second solution adding ID_office at where condition. It seems to work fine. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you pass the values of year, month and day inside the sub query, there is only one row available for the lag function which is always going to give you a null value. Correct way should be:

```
UPDATE table1 f1
   SET f1.operations_yesterday =
       (WITH table1_lag AS (SELECT ff.YEAR,
                                   ff.MONTH,
                                   ff.DAY,
                                   lag(ff.operations, 1, 0) over(ORDER BY ff.YEAR, ff.MONTH, ff.DAY) AS yesterday
                              FROM table1 ff)
           SELECT f2.yesterday
             FROM table1_lag f2
            WHERE f1.year = f2.year
              AND f1.month = f2.month
              AND f1.day = f2.day);
```

Comment: Thanks San, I am still modifying your solution and trying it. I will answer you as soon as I get something.

Comment: I added "ID_Office" at the end of the ORDER BY and at the final WHERE, but the result is not correct. It should get the previus row from the same ID_Office, but right now its getting the previus row ignoring ID_OFFICE. 

Is there a way I can group by ID_OFFICE using your code? 

Because, except for the addtion of this field, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If there are missing days and you want values from day before yesterday in such case then you could use `merge`:

```
merge into table1 t1
using (select lag(operations, 1, 0) 
              over (partition by id_office order by year, month, day) lop
         from table1 t) t2
on (t1.rowid = t2.rowid)
when matched then update set operations_yesterday = t2.lop;
```

Test data:

```
create table table1(Year number(4), Month number(2), Day number(2), 
    ID_Office number(5), Operations number(4), Operations_yesterday number(4));

insert into table1 values (2016, 12, 31, 9555, 500, null);
insert into table1 values (2017,  1,  1, 9555, 600, null);
insert into table1 values (2017,  1,  2, 9555, 750, null);
insert into table1 values (2017,  1,  3, 9556, 800, null);
insert into table1 values (2017,  1,  5, 9556, 400, null);
```

... and after `merge`:

```
 select * from table1;

 YEAR MONTH DAY ID_OFFICE OPERATIONS OPERATIONS_YESTERDAY
----- ----- --- --------- ---------- --------------------
 2016    12  31      9555        500                    0
 2017     1   1      9555        600                  500
 2017     1   2      9555        750                  600
 2017     1   3      9556        800                    0
 2017     1   5      9556        400                  800
```